# Shopware 6 - Create product programmatically

Tags: import, product, shopware6

I have a command script to import products from csv file.

The code i use to create the product is:

```
$this->productRepository->create([[
        'id'            => Uuid::randomHex(),
        'name'          => 'exampls',
        'taxId'         => 'b6e10c80b24946a48bb74e742d280c75',
        'stock'         => 999,
        'createdAt'     => '2022-01-01T10:17:05+02:00',
        'price'         => [
            [
                'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
                'gross'      => 99,
                'net'        => 99,
                'linked'     => true,
            ]
        ],
        'productNumber' => $suffix,
        'visibilities'  => [
            [
                'salesChannelId' => '5ce47a708e484e4d8c20221f8cdfa08f',
                'visibility'     => ProductVisibilityDefinition::VISIBILITY_ALL,
            ],
        ],
    ]], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

I get the following error:

```
     An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `version_id`, `parent_version_id`, `product_manufacturer_versio  
  n_id`, `tax_id`, `product_media_version_id`, `cms_page_version_id`, `price`, `product_number`, `stock`, `restock_time`, `active`, `  
  is_closeout`, `purchase_steps`, `min_purchase`, `shipping_free`, `created_at`) VALUES ('���zgL��vc�.�p','���jK¾K��u,4%','���  
  jK¾K��u,4%','���jK¾K��u,4%','��
                                 ��IF���Nt-(
                                            u','���jK¾K��u,4%','���jK¾K��u,4%','{\"cb7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca\":{\  
  "currencyId\":\"b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca\",\"gross\":99.0,\"net\":99.0,\"linked\":true}}','62e2977934944','999',NULL,'1','0  
  ','1','1','0','2022-01-01 08:17:05.000');':
```

What could i do to get it working? And if there is another way to approach this, i'm open for suggestions. Just started learning Shopware :)

Comment: First try to get the full error message ....

Answer (score 2):

At first glance this looks to be correct. The error message seems to be incomplete. It should say after the query why it failed, be it a syntax error or a wrong foreign key. The latter would be my best guess at what could fail the moment, have you checked all the uuids to exist in their corresponding tables like `tax`, `currency` and `sales_channel`?